# Character Encoding issue in PHP and HTML

Tags: php, encoding, character

In database I have stored some ID's the values are something like "A001" OR "A-001". The value is perfectly stored in database but when I display them in browser it gets converted into numeric value 2.

How can I display the exact string on browser. I have tried with echo, print and var_dump()

Comment: Please include relevant code (insert and select queries at least), hard to find a mistake from thin air.

Comment: Also, table structure might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide more information for replication, you would get good answers. 
I doubt I understood your question. 
Assuming database is MySQL, this code should work:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect(YOUR_HOST,YOUR_ID,YOUR_PW);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select ID from YOUR_TABLE where ID='A001'");
    echo $result[0];  // A001 would be shown in browser
?>
```

Comment: This is the value I gave "A-001" as input to a text field on html side. On backend I am using MySQL, the input is saved as it is "A-001". But when I display the result from MYSQL on browser, it is showing me "14". If in database I save "A001", it displays "2" on browser. It seems to be that there is some hex or some other encoding being done.

Comment: @Meghakaur Is "A-001" or "A001" stored in MySQL exactly? If Yes, then above php code would work.

Comment: Yes, this is saved like "A-001" or "A001". But the code is not working.

Comment: @Meghakaur How do you get values from MySQL in your php code?